# Why is the data constant not initialized?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I have these lines of code:

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "csv")!

let dataTable : MLDataTable

do {
  dataTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)

} catch {
  print(error)
}


let (trainingCSVData, testCSVData) = dataTable.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 0)
```

I have this error in the last line

> constant `dataTable` used before being initialized...

What's causing that?

Comment: Think about it: What if the `try ...` fails?

Comment: Actually you can do `let dataTable = try! MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)` (as you did with the bundle) – a failure would be a *programmig error* and should be caught early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the entire *good* code always in the `do` scope

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "csv")!
do {
    let dataTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)
    let (trainingCSVData, testCSVData) = dataTable.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 0)
    // continue
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

However a file in the application bundle cannot be changed at runtime and is supposed to contain valid data

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "csv")!
let dataTable = try! MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)
let (trainingCSVData, testCSVData) = dataTable.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 0)
```

If the code crashes you made a **design** mistake

Comment: I was suspecting I had to put it inside the scope but I could not believe that because it is a very bad design. Imaging to initialize a lot of stuff with try. Sudden you have stuff, inside stuff, inside stuff, ad infinitum and a lot of `catch` at the end. Man, this is very bad. Is there any alternative to that and keeping it safe?

Comment: A non-optional constant must be initialized in any case (branch) before being used. Force unwrapping things inside the application bundle is safe if the design is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because the try might fail so move the assignment inside the do/catch. If the init doesn't throw the next line will be executed ok

```
do {
  dataTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)
  let (trainingCSVData, testCSVData) = dataTable.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 0)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```